# How does proxy work in Virtualmin, and can I forward whatever.domain.example to an internal ip address with a different port?

Tags: reverse-proxy

In Virtualmin, I've read that you can set up a proxy website under a subdomain.

All traffic on port 80 hits Apache where there are multiple virtual servers sharing the internal server IP.

I have a separate machine, a Raspberry Pi3 running a web service on port 8123.

If I create a subdomain.mydomain.example, can I get Apache to load the http://internalip:8123 site and send it to the requestor?

Is this what a reverse proxy is?

Comment: Yes, this is what a reverse proxy is for - see [Apache - Reverse Proxy Guide](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html). How to configure this is a bit outside the scope of this site, which is primarily for [operating websites](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html). Generally for advanced server configurations, we point users to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/). They don't permit questions about control panels, otherwise I'd migrate this there, but if you edit this to just focus on the required Apache configuration, they might be able to help.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://www.webmin.com/apache.html) guide might help (check the last topic).

Comment: @dan, the link you suggested talks about a different topic, not the one the OP is asking about. OP is asking about how a feature in the Virtualmin panel works.

Comment: @SamSirry That's incorrect, the link _is_ relevant to [Virtualmin](https://www.webmin.com/virtualmin.html), which is the open source module that sits on top of Webmin and helps non-root users manage shared hosting accounts. The last topic covers how proxies work with both.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that Virtualmin feature will work as you describe, however, note that the `HOST` header in the secondary request will be set to the address entered in the proxy's target field, which may  affect how the site responds (if it changes behaviour according to the host header).